# Запуск стандартного браузера из TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Как реализовать запуск стандартного браузера из `TWebBrowser`? Ну, например, я загружаю от туда страницу и там такое:

```
<a href="http://ya.ru" target=_blank>12345</a>
```

при клике открывается отдельное окно `IE`. А можно ли реализовать запуск стандартного браузера (опера, хром)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть рецептик. Вешаем на событие `OnBeforeNavigate2` обработчик с кодом:

```
Cancel := (URL <> FCurrURL);
if Cancel then
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(VarToStr(URL)), '', '.', SW_SHOW);
```

здесь `FCurrURL` переменная где заранее должен быть записан адрес страницы которая загружена в `TWebBrowser`